# Read file from SharePoint in android via graph

Tags: android, permissions, sharepoint-2010, android-manifest

Its my first time to work with MSAL.

i am using the graph api to read data but i'm getting a sharepoint file link .

i want to download that file into my app but it is giving 403 error code but i can access that file without login with that url on chrome or  any other browser .

Q1 is there any special permission required to access share point file on android ?

Q2  can someone share sample auth json file or manifest file ?

Q3 any example to read file in android java or kotlin ?

Answer (score 0):

these are the permissions required when requesting the Download Content API as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) mentioned, and you can first decode the obtained token in the [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) to ensure you get the permission. Hope this helps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6DBr.png)